# Sending weekly email to users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mailchimp, mandrill

I plan on sending a weekly email to each of my users with an update on activities depending on their preferences. The problem is I am unsure if I should use Mailchimp or Mandrill for this. I was initially thinking about Mailchimp since I would send the emails in bulk, but then I realized that the emails will be somewhat tailored to each user, so I thought I would ask. Any thoughts?

Comment: You know that MailChimp now owns Mandrill right? And that its a paid add-on..

Comment: That's true, I forgot that. But I was using Mandrill as an example of a transactional email service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use either. I would have said Mandrill until they coupled it more tightly with Mailchimp.  I'd look at Mailgun, sendgrid, smtp.com, or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am using Postmark and am pretty happy with it so far.

Comment: I agree that transactional services are best for this, however I think Mandrill is plenty well suited to this task, even after the coupling. If you already have access to Mandrill, Mandrill is totally fine.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified my issue with Mandrill now is having to pay for Mailchimp, but yes, if that's not an issue then Mandrill is fantastic.